Tikz Latex for Actual/Future Timeline Value of Money in Financial Mathematics
I am trying to replicate the following timeline for future/present values of money:

However, I do not know how to add the curves (preferably with an arrow ending) from years 0 to 1, 2,... Up to now, I have only the basic structure without the curves.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) -- node[below=1mm,pos=0.6,scale=2] {$\cdots$} 
    (10,0)node[right=4mm]{(periods)};
  \foreach \x/\y in {0/0,1/1,2/2,3/3,9/$n-1$,10/$n$}{
  \draw[line width=1pt] (\x,-2mm)node[below](\x){\strut\y} -- (\x,2mm)node[above]{$\$ 1$};
 }
\draw[-latex] (0,-7mm) -- +(0,-10mm)node[below]{$A_{ni}$};
 \draw[-latex] (10,-7mm) -- +(0,-10mm)node[below]{$S_{ni}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Try \draw[cyan, ~>] (0,0) to[out=330, in=210] (2,0); or similar.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick] (0,0) -- node[below=2pt, pos=0.6, scale=2]{$\cdots$} (10,0) node[right=4mm]{(periods)};
\foreach \x/\y in {0/0,1/1,2/2,3/3,9/$n-1$,10/$n$}{
\draw[cyan, -{Latex[scale=1.5]}] (0,0) to[bend right=40] (\x,0);
\draw[very thick] (\x,-0.2) node[below=10pt, anchor=base]{\y} -- (\x,0.2) node[above]{$\$ 1$};
}
\draw[-Latex] (0,-0.7) -- +(0,-1) node[below]{$A_{ni}$};
\draw[-Latex] (10,-0.7) -- +(0,-1) node[below]{$S_{ni}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


